# How to bind list of object to DataGrid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, datagrid

This is my code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private List<Word> _words;

    public List<Word> Words
    {
        get => _words;
        set
        {
            _words = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Words");
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MeaningGroup group1 = new MeaningGroup()
        {
            Synonyms = new List<string> {"synonym1", "synonym2", "synonym3"},
            Acronyms = new List<string> {"acronym1", "acronym2"}
        };

        MeaningGroup group2 = new MeaningGroup()
        {
            Synonyms = new List<string> { "synonym1"},
            Acronyms = new List<string> { "acronym1", "acronym2", "acronym3" }
        };

        MeaningGroup group3 = new MeaningGroup()
        {
            Synonyms = new List<string> { "synonym1", "synonym2" },
            Acronyms = new List<string> { }
        };

        MeaningGroup group4 = new MeaningGroup()
        {
            Synonyms = new List<string> { "synonym1" },
            Acronyms = new List<string> { "acronym1", "acronym2", "acronym3","acronym4" }
        };

        Word word1 = new Word() {Name = "word1",MeaningGroups = new List<MeaningGroup>() {group1, group2}};
        Word word2 = new Word() { Name = "word2", MeaningGroups = new List<MeaningGroup>() { group3, group4 } };
        Word word3 = new Word() { Name = "word3", MeaningGroups = new List<MeaningGroup>() { group1, group2,group4 } };
        Word word4 = new Word() { Name = "word4", MeaningGroups = new List<MeaningGroup>() { group3 } };

        Words = new List<Word> {word1, word2, word3, word4};

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public class Word
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public List<MeaningGroup> MeaningGroups { get; set; }

}

public class MeaningGroup
{
    public List<string> Synonyms { get; set; }
    public List<string> Acronyms { get; set; }
}
```

And this is MainWindow.xaml code:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp4.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp4"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Words}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Synonym and acronyms">
               <!-- How binding? -->
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

I want to bind data objects like this:
[image]

Comment: For starters you've got a problem with your main list binding, you're creating a local variable called `Words` and setting that as the DataContext, but then your `ItemsControl` is trying to bind to a property called `Words` Either make `Words` a property of MainWindow and set that as your DataContext instead, or change the binding to `Binding="{Binding}"`. Other than that's it's really not clear what you're trying to do, other than  eventually render a collapsed union of Synonyms and Acronyms as a single-column list of tags or something?

Comment: @MarkFeldman I've updated the code. please review again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer below solves this problem, but I will suggest another way. As said above, first you need to add `DataContext = this` in your code-behide. Then just change the xaml markup as follows:

```
     <Grid>
        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Words}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Synonym and acronyms">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MeaningGroups}">
                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Synonyms}">
                                                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                            <WrapPanel/>
                                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5 5 0 0">
                                                            <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding}"/>
                                                            </Border>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                </ItemsControl>
                                                <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Acronyms}">
                                                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                            <WrapPanel/>
                                                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                                                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                        <DataTemplate>
                                                            <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Black" CornerRadius="5" Background="Red" Margin="5 5 0 0">
                                                            <TextBlock Margin="3" Text="{Binding}"/>
                                                            </Border>
                                                        </DataTemplate>
                                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                                </ItemsControl>
                                            </StackPanel>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                                </ItemsControl>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

As a result, we will get
[image]

Comment: I've not forgotten DataContext. I've put it in the Xaml.

Comment: Good solution, but it comes with the caveat that the tags won't wrap if there's not enough horizontal space to accommodate them. OP didn't specify desired behavior of course, so it might be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite understand what you mean, but if you want to bind properties to columns, you can do this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Words}">
   <DataGrid.Columns>
     <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now the "Name" of each element will be added to this column. But if you want to add more than one property to a column, you'll have to add `DataGridTemplateColumn`:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Words}">       
   <DataGrid.Columns>
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
      <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Synonyms and Acronyms">
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
               <StackPanel>
                     //There will be all logic. For example
                     //<TextBlock Text="{Binding Synonyms}"/>
                     //<TextBlock Text="{Binding Acronyms}"/>
               </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
         </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
      </DataGridTemplateColumn>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But sorry, I don't know what would happen if the column is to pass a collection of strings (as in your example). And I'm sorry if I misunderstood you

Answer (score 1):

Your updated code still has a binding mistake, you need to add this to the bottom of your constructor:

```
    this.DataContext = this;
```

The main problem with the code you've posted is that you're trying to merge your Synonym and Acronym arrays into a single list, which is really something that should be done before passing the data to your view layer. I'll use a converter to do this task after-the-fact, but keep in mind that's it's something you should probably fix up later.

In any case what you're trying to achieve is relatively straightforward. Use a DataGridTemplateColumn to declare a custom column type and set its content to an `ItemsControl` (its default panel is a vertical StackPanel). Each element of the stack panel is a `MeaningGroup`, so just use another ItemsControl to render your tags, and set its `ItemsPanelTemplate` to be a horizontal layout instead (I've used a WrapPanel). Put all that together and you get this:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <behaviors:ListUnionConverter x:Key="ListUnionConverter" />

    <DataTemplate x:Key="TagTemplate">
        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5" Padding="5">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="TagListTemplate">
        <ItemsControl ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TagTemplate}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
                <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ListUnionConverter}">
                    <Binding Path="Synonyms" />
                    <Binding Path="Acronyms" />
                </MultiBinding>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsSource>
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        </ItemsControl>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="CellTemplate">
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding MeaningGroups}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource TagListTemplate}" />
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Words}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Synonym and acronyms" IsReadOnly="True" CellTemplate="{StaticResource CellTemplate}" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

You'll also need the code for the converter that I'm using to join the Synonymns and Acronyms into a single list. Again, you should either replace this with something more robust or, preferably, fix up your data structures to better match the view requirements:

Result:

```
public class ListUnionConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (values[0] as IEnumerable<string>).Concat(values[1] as IEnumerable<string>).ToArray();
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

[image]

UPDATE: I just noticed the requirement for the colors to be different. You could also use a converter to do that if you absolutely had to, but that's a really messy solution. The correct way to implement this is with an intermediate view model and with both synonyms and acronyms merged into a single list.

Comment: I've not forgotten DataContext. I've put it in the Xaml: `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`

Comment: I didn't accept your answer, not because it wasn't good, because doing your better solution under present circumstances is out of my current ability . I scare perfectionism. Therefore I want you to continue answer my future questions. thank you for your time.